# How to catch large texts with a DialogFlow entity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm building a chatbot that retrieves projects information given the project name and the owner ID, to achieve this, i have two action parameters **project** of type **sys.any** and **carnet** that is a regex entity. The problem is when the project name is larger than normal, that is at least a project name with 5 words in it,in this scenario the builtin entity **sys.any** does not catch the whole project name. In other cases the action parameter **project** also captures the value of **carnet** in it.

Is there a way in dialogflow to catch large texts as the value of an action parameter?

[image]

Comment: It would help us a great deal if you could update your question to show what the `carnet` regex is and some examples to illustrate the problem you're seeing so we can attempt to duplicate the issue.